# How to not evaluate bolean expression with sympy?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

### I have a executions like this :

```py
 >>> sympy.sympify("x == []")
 False
```

I don't understand why sympy evaluates directly when we doesn't know x

but that works for numeric expression :

```
 >>> sympy.sympify("x + 1")
 x + 1
 >>> sympy.sympify("x + 1").subs({"x":1})
 2
```

### But i want :

```py
 >>> sympy.sympify("x == []")
 x == []
 >>> sympy.sympify("x == []").subs({"x":[]})
 True
```

Why does sympy not work like this and how do I get the result I expect?

Comment: `==` is syntactic equality whereas `Eq` is mathematical equality. See [SymPy's Gochas & Pitfalls](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs). However, even then, your expression has issues because SymPy cannot handle lists or empty arrays and so what you want might not be possible currently.

Comment: Dare I say, maybe Python's `eval` function is better suited for this?